# how to hide a row in mui data grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a data grid using MUI. I want to hide a few rows and not display them based on a given condition and if a particular value exists in a column. How do I hide it? There seems to be props such as

```
hide
```

for columns but there is nothing for rows.
EDIT
The code is as follows
I want to hide the row from being displayed if a value exists in the 4th column (field: 'recvDistLocId')
and I want to hide the rows only when I press a button in the toolbar. So basically, its like a filter. Initially, all the data should be displayed and if I click the button, all rows with a value in the 4th column should disappear.

```
const columns = []
columns.push({
      field: 'code',
      headerName: nowrapHeader(appLanguages.serialCode[lang]),
      flex: 1,
      getApplyQuickFilterFn: getApplyFilterFnSameYear
    });

    columns.push({
      field: 'brandId',
      headerName: nowrapHeader(appLanguages.brand[lang]),
      renderCell: (params) =>
        getSelectCustomBodyRender(this.getBrandOptionMap(), params.row.brandId),
      flex: 1,
    });

    columns.push({
      field: 'slip',
      headerName: nowrapHeader(appLanguages.slipNum[lang]),

      renderCell: (params) => this.getSlipText(params.row.slip),

      flex: 1,
    });
columns.push({
      field: 'recvDistLocId',
      headerName: 'RecvDistLocId',
      flex: 1,
      hide: true,
    });


/////This is the main data grid element code in the render()

<div style={{ height: 640, width: '100%' }}>
            <DataGrid
              sx={{
                '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderCheckbox .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainer': {
                  display: 'none',
                },
              }}
              rows={serialsList || []}
              columns={columns}
              rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 100]}
              checkboxSelection={this.state.cancelShipFlag ? true : false}
              disableSelectionOnClick={false}
              components={{
                Toolbar: NewToolbar,
              }}
              onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
                const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
                const selectedRows = rowData.filter((row) => selectedIDs.has(row.id));

                this.setState({ rowinfo: selectedRows });
                this.setState({ selectedrows: ids });
                //console.log('Selected rows: ' + this.state.selectedrows);
              }}
              selectionModel={this.state.selectedrows}
            />
          </div>
```

Comment: please share your code of mui grid element

Comment: filter them out in your data based on that condition. Instead of hiding the rows just do not include them in the data you pass to the data grid.

Answer (score 1):

filter the data based on the condition

```
// use setFilterValue to set the value of the clicked column e.g. recvDistLocId
const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = React.useState()

// assuming serialsList is array of strings
// use same case for comparing values
// use row.toLowerCase() !== filterValue.toLowerCase()
const rows = (serialsList || []).filter(row => row !== filterValue)
```

Then pass rows to the data grid

```
<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  ....
```